# Block visitors access to .xml files but allow flash to open them

Tags: linux, flash, apache, .htaccess, file-permissions

I want to deny permission of visitors to access http://example.com/xml_folder/xml_file1.xml and any other .xml file in the xml_folder. I can do that easily modifying folder permisions.
The problem is that I also have a small flash on my website that needs to access those .xml files and once I remove "read" from "Public permissions" the flash can't access the files either (which I think is pretty normal).

So .. my question is: how do I restrict visitors to access the .xml files but not the flash.swf file ?
Btw, it's running on a linux vps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  If Flash can retrieve the file then so can a user who watches with FireBug and captures the URL.

Comment: Can't I detect if the file is opened by flash player rather than the browser ? I know that you can fake the header that is sent but this is for advanced users. I need to have a minimum security.

Comment: Any user who knows there's an XML file involved will likely know how to fake the necessary headers by watching the traffic in Firebug or Fiddler.  The only people you'll keep out are the ones who probably wouldn't know to look anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try hosting a password-protected HTTPS virtual server with just the XML files. Use the username and password in the flash (This flash code must hide the user name and password as well). I'm not familiar with flash programming. But I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm not into flash programming either but I see your point. I'll look into it, thanks!